# Composer private git repositories with unique configuration item for the same server

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have a private git repository located at username@somedomain.com, that i access with ssh.

I need to include 2 projects from the same server, and i do like this:

```
"require": {
    "proj1": "dev-master",
    "proj2": "dev-master",
 },


"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "username@somedomain.com:proj1.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "username@somedomain.com:proj2.git"
        }
    ]
```

May happen that these repo grow in number. Is there any chance where i can configure something like

```
"url": "username@somedomain.com"
```

and let composer resolve where to find the packages?

Please note that i don't want to use satis or any other package manager.

Answer (score 1):

There is only way to handle private projects without direct definding insided `composer.json` -- use Satis or Toran Proxy.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

Comment: Forgot to mention that i don't want to use satis and the such

Comment: @brazorf , sorry, it's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Composer allows you to add repositories that will also be scanned for packages in addition to using Packagist.

Note that you didn't specify which package is to be found in these repositories because Composer will scan these for `composer.json` itself and detect which packages are available (one repository might contain more than one package in different branches!).

Because every repository is independent of each other, you have to mention them all individually.

Also note that Composer only allows to add these repositories on the root level, so you have to repeat every repository that is being used in your dependencies again in the root project, even if that root project does not have a direct dependency to a package that is provided in such a repository.

The way to avoid this is to have a Packagist-like repository that is created via Satis, Toran or a local installation of Packagist itself. I recommend going that way even if you say you don't want to.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to *now*, because the projects i rely on are not ready to be delivered. When they will, they'll be on packagist as they should - i'm searching for a temp solution.